# Google ML Engine: Failed to load model: (Error code: 0)

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm using ML Engine to serve predictions.  I used `Python: 2.7, Framework: Tensorflow, Framework version: 1.8, Runtime version: 1.8` but am getting back:

`Failed to load model:  (Error code: 0)`

I googled around but most issues have a more specific error than what I do.  Is using the latest framework and runtime versions a bad idea / problematic?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try running `gcloud ml-engine local predict ...` and report the result in your question?

Comment: Can you indicate how you are sending the prediction request?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using python 3.7 and framework = scikit-learn. It returned error code 0. My problem was using an algorithm that did not have a "predict" method implemented. Error code 0 seems to be a generic error class for internal model related issues.